# SQL query to get the list of names that starts with a given query followed by a white space

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

in an SQL query on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I would like to do the following:

I have a table `User` that has a column `Name`

I also have a parameter `@QueryString` declared as nvarchar

```
Declare @QueryString AS nvarchar(100)
```

I would like to query the table `User` and get all the users in the condition that their "Name" starts with `@QueryString` Followed by a white space.

Example:

Lets say I have this table

```
      UserId            Name
+---------------+-----------------+
|      0        |      bear jon   |
|      1        |      jon        |
|      2        |      jonson     |
|      3        |      jon wayne  |
|      4        |      jone white |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

if @QueryString = "jon"

I want to get only

```
+---------------+-----------------+
|      3        |      jon wayne  |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

As it was the only one that starts with "jon" followed by a white space.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM User
WHERE User.Name START WITH (@QueryString + " ")
```

I tried to play with the `LIKE` function but without result. I can't figure out how to use the params with the LIKES and concatenate the " " to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM User
WHERE User.Name LIKE @QueryString + ' %'
```

Comment: thank you but how can I use the parameter @QueryString instead of hard coding 'jon'

Comment: `LIKE @QueryString + ' %'`

Comment: thank you it worked, I should have thought of directly concatenating.